# Interpreting cron output

Tags: permissions, rhel, cron

```
====================================================
====================================================
CHECK_BEGIN: DO_CRON
====================================================
====================================================
[FILE]: CRON.ALLOW
-rw-------. 1 root root 0 Sep  1  2017 /etc/cron.allow
====================================================
====================================================
====================================================
[FILE]: CRON.DENY
-rw------- 1 root root 0 May  5  2018 /etc/cron.deny
====================================================
====================================================
Checking permissions on /var/spool/cron
drwx------. 2 root root 4096 May  5  2018 /var/spool/cron
====================================================
```

How do I interpret the above output?

1. The root user can always use cron, regardless of the usernames listed in the access control files?
2. If the file cron.allow exists, only users listed in it are allowed to use cron, and the cron.deny file is ignored?

Therefore in this case, only the users listed within /etc/cron.allow are allowed access to the cron daemon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `cron.allow` file exists, it lists the users that may use `cron`.  If it does not exist, the `cron.deny` file is checked.

If the `cron.deny` file exists, it lists the users that may not use `cron`. This file is not consulted if the `cron.allow` file exists.

If all users are denied the use of cron (as in your case, since the `cron.allow` file exists, and is empty), only root is able to use `cron`. This is the same that would happen if neither file existed.

The most common configuration is to have an empty `cron.deny` file and no `cron.allow` file. This would allow everyone the use of `cron`.

This also applies to `at.deny` and `at.allow` for using `at` to schedule commands.